# MongoDB: Remove all array entries except the last X entries

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

[Node.JS MongoDB Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) is used. 
The database entries look like that:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("224444202654a21928801814"),
    category: "Test", 
    entries: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId("324444202dd4a21328802214"),
            username: "Tester",
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId("324444232dd4a21328802215"),
            username: "Tester2",
        }
        [many more...]
    ]
}
```

There are thousands of objects in the entries array.
The last array entries are the newest ones. 
Now all objects should be deleted inside the entries array except the last 50 entries.
Is there a possibility to achieve that with one update/remove call? Maybe with the [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator?

Comment: I am able to get entries which are not in last 50 records. Now finding the way to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve what you want with the $slice operator.  I think using the javascript [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) operator within cursor [`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) is your best bet. Try this out:

```js
db.foo.find({}).forEach( function(doc) { 
    db.foo.update(
        {_id:doc._id}, 
        {$set:{entries:doc.entries.slice(doc.entries.length - 50)}}
    ) 
})
```

**Note:** The above command would run fine in the Mongo Shell.

Comment: Okay, I will use this solution for the moment.